# React Native Props passed to Child View won't behave as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to RN, trying to get around it by trial and erroring a lot. I'm currently stuck with this :

I have one parent view which is like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

class ParentView extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flex:0.14, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <Image
                            source = {require('./assets/image1.png')}
                            resizeMode= 'contain'
                            style={{flex:1, height:null, width:null}}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:3}}>
                        <Button title='dummytitle' onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Child', {
                            dbpath: 'db.category.subcategory',
                            })}
                        />
                    </View>
```

etc...

This part works OK. In child view, I'm trying to import JSON data from a file like so :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';
import db from './db/quizDB';


class Quiz extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.qno = 0
        this.score = 0
        quiz = this.props.navigation.getParam('dbpath');
        arrnew = Object.keys(quiz).map(function(k) {return quiz[k]});
        this.state = { 
            question: arrnew[this.qno].question,
        }
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{flex:2}}>
                    <View style={styles.Question}>
                        <Text>{this.state.question}</Text>
                    </View>
```

etc..

{this.state.question} returns nothing, it's just empty. But if I hardcode quiz as quiz = db.category.subcategory, it does work, {this.state.question} displays the expected content.

What am I missing there ? It seems like props aren't processed as I'd like them to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either declare `quiz` and `arrnew` with `let` or `var`, or attach them to the state.

In addition, in React, standard practice is not to directly attach properties to the class instance, like you've done here:

`this.qno = 0
this.score = 0`

These should probably be local variables, but if you need to, these could be attached to the state instead.

Comment: I tried to edit my constructor like this :

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     var qno = 0
     var score = 0
     var quiz = this.props.navigation.getParam('quiz');
     var arrnew = Object.keys(quiz).map(function(k) {return quiz[k]});
     this.state = { 
      showAlert: false,
      question: arrnew[qno].question,
     }
    };

But still renturning blank. Did I do this right ?

Comment: Try logging the state at the beginning of your render function to see if it contains what it should

Comment: Well, it returns undefined. That's where I'm confused. quizDB being an imported Component in Child view,is it a problem when I set its var quiz from the previous Parent quiz prop ?

Comment: It looks like `db` isn't defined at all in the parent view, so yes, that's a problem. `db` is a React component?

Comment: That's it, db wasn't defined in the parent view. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, I was being stupid. I just imported db in the Parent view and set the quiz prop directly from there. My mistake was to set it as a string...